# How to call computer name in a PowerShell script and then rename the last 5 characters?

Tags: powershell

The below will retrieve the computer name `XX01234XYZ05`

```
$computer = gc env:computername
```

I then need to change `XYZ05` to `ABC01` so I end up with `XX01234ABC01` and then use that to map to a path location e.g. `\\XX01234ABC01\D$`

Comment: gc (get-content) is  used to get the content of a file, it's useless here

Answer (score 2):

You can use -replace:

```
$env:computername -replace '.....$', 'ABC01'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$host=$env:computername -replace "XYZ05","ABC01"
New-PSDrive -Name "t" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$host\d$"
```

Comment: Thanks... XYZ05 will be different across devices e.g. XYZ01, XYZ02... Is it possible to say change character 8-12 to be ABC01 or do something similar to cmd /c net use v: \\%computername:~0,7%ABC01\ where you can take the first 7 characters of the computer name and add ABC01?

Comment: Yes use @jisaak code to replace the last 5 characters